# Why does this function work with apply but not with sapply?

Tags: r, apply, sapply

I have a set of companies belonging to different stock indices. I want to create different subsets, based on the names of the indices.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
cs.ind.sp500 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
cs.ind.spsc1500 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
cs.ind.dax40 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
dat <- data.frame(cs.ind.sp500, cs.ind.spsc1500, cs.ind.dax40)
```

I have now written the following simple function. It should go through the different rows and see if at least one of the dummies, which stand for index membership, are equal to 1.

```
fun<- function(x) {
  if (any(x == 1)) {
    1
  } else {
    0
  }
}
```

I want to apply this function to different sets of vectors, like below:

```
dat$sel.compall <- sapply(X = dat[grepl("^cs.ind.", names(dat))], FUN = fun)

dat$sel.compbase <- sapply(X = dat[grepl("^cs.ind.", names(dat)) & !grepl("^cs.ind.spsc1500", names(dat))], FUN = fun)
```

However, what happens is the following:

The first call throws an error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, sel.compall, value = c(1, 1, 1)) : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 10
```

The second call allocates 1 to all the rows, even though the condition does not hold for all of them.

When I apply via `apply`, like ...

```
dat$sel.compbase <- apply(X = dat[grepl("^cs.ind.", names(dat)) & !grepl("^cs.ind.spsc1500", names(dat))], FUN = fun, MARGIN = 1)
```

... it seems to work.

Why can I not use `sapply` here? I do not see a reason why `sapply` would not be able to simplify the output in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sapply` function apply your FUN on columns. To `apply` on columns, you need to set `MARGIN = 2`

Doyou want to apply on lines or on columns?

Comment: Hi! I want the function to check each row across the indexed columns whether at least one (any) of the values in these columns is = 1. So I guess this means applying by row

Comment: Ok then you can't use sapply since it's applys on columns (While using sapply your data.frame is seen as a list of columns.)

Comment: OK, so in this case it is best to use apply with MARGIN = 1?

Also, can you tell me why calling the function directly also gives only 1's? (e.g.,
`dat$sel.compbase <-fun(x = dat[grepl("^cs.ind.", names(dat))])`

Comment: Because your function `fun`checks if the is any `1` in dat. You should change fun to perform computation on rows ;)